# QGIS: Modifying a CRS from m to mm

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am looking to align a CAD file that uses a customised version of the CRS SVY21 where it is in mm instead of m.

My objective is to create/customise a new CRS from the data within SYV21 (see below):

```
Extent: 103.59, 1.13, 104.07, 1.47
Proj4: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=1.366666666666667 +lon_0=103.8333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=28001.642 +y_0=38744.572 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

I thought it was as simple as change it to this:

```
Extent: 103.59, 1.13, 104.07, 1.47
Proj4: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=1.366666666666667 +lon_0=103.8333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=*28001642* +y_0=*38744572* +ellps=WGS84 +units=*mm* +no_defs
```

However this only shows errors. Can someone see where I am going wrong and direct me to the right path?

Comment: Could be related https://issues.qgis.org/issues/9414 and https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/508

Comment: I don't know about the extent, but the custom CRS `+proj=tmerc +lat_0=1.366666666666667 +lon_0=103.8333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=28001642 +y_0=38744572 +ellps=WGS84 +units=mm +no_defs` doesn't return errors here.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://proj.maptools.org/gen_parms.html :

**False Easting/Northing**

**Note that these values are always expressed in meters even if the coordinate system is some other units.**

So the +x_0 and +y_0 won't change if you change the units from m to mm.